# remove opacity from parent box for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

```
<div id="loginBox">
        <!--h3>Login</h3-->
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <!--?php csrf_token(); ?-->
        <input type="hidden" name="do" value="scplogin">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="name" value="" placeholder="Username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
            <input type="password" name="passwd" id="pass" placeholder="Password" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
        </fieldset>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
        <span></span>
        <div id="label"></div>
        </form>
</div>
```

for loginBox:
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#002d72, endColorstr=#002d72);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

but I don't want child input inherit them, I've already solved them in Chrome, not sure how to solve them in IE?

Comment: by the way, use rgba could solve the problem for chrome like this: background:rgba(0,45,114,0.5);

Comment: if there anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an aRGB string and remove the opacity `-ms-filter` and change your gradient filter to include the aRGB strings. Assuming you want 50% opacity on each of the colors:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#80002d72, endColorstr=#80002d72);
```

Here's a list of the HEX alpha value codes:

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

You need to make sure this is **in front** of your current hex code.

Or a fall back in IE could be a PNG in an IE specific style sheet, if you already have it working in other browsers.

==== **UPDATE** ====

Lastly - I would look at a javascript option, I've just tested this and it's working in IE7.

It's called ThatsNotYoChild.js.

You can find a working codepen here:

http://codepen.io/impressivewebs/details/CyfED

and it's simple to implement, you just call `thatsNotYoChild('parent');`.

You can read more about this on Impressive Webs http://www.impressivewebs.com/fixing-parent-child-opacity/

Comment: thanks first.but seems if only add the filter you provided. not opacity displayed. but if I added the  filter: alpha(opacity=50); it will affect the child input opacity, which is really confusing.

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in? And version?

Comment: currently testing on IE7

Comment: It should work in IE5 and above, I've just updated my answer with a javascript option that's easy to implement!

Comment: I post my html, seems the JS reports error for me,parent.innerHTML is null